# Expected ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me nuts, my Google searches point to speechmark problems but I cannot fathom how this is the case with my code below, especially after I have alternated between single and double quote marks but still no joy:

```
$( ".block-nav .c-4" ).hover(
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".block-nav .c-4 .white-overlay").css("display", "none");
    },300);
);
```

Any pointers appreciated...

Comment: hover expects a function, you are assigning an integer to the method since that is what setTimeout returns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to use a `function() {}` wrapper :

```
$( ".block-nav .c-4" ).hover( function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".block-nav .c-4 .white-overlay").css("display", "none");
    },300); }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want a `300ms` delay after the user hovers an element, then you want to run that function.  If that's the case, try this (wrapping your `setTimeout` call in a function):

```
$( ".block-nav .c-4" ).on('mouseenter', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".block-nav .c-4 .white-overlay").css("display", "none");
    },300);
});
```